# get full path through file uploader in Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

I am using telerik controls in asp.net

For uploading a file i am using, `RadUpload`

**I gone through following links:**

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/upload/get-full-path-from-uplad-control.aspx#1044702

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/async-upload/how-to-get-full-path-using-radasyncupload-control.aspx

**Made Code As Follows:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                string fileName= Server.MapPath( RadUpload1.UploadedFiles[i].GetName());
            }
```

**Its giving me path:**

```
E:\WebBasedNewSoft\NewSoft\NewSoft\colnames.xlsx
```

this is the path where my solution files are stored.

**I wanted to get path of file selected for upload.**

Eg. if uploaded file is on c drive , it should give me path:

```
C:\colnames.xlsx
```

But its not giving me appropriate path.

What mistake am i making?

What should be appropriate line in for loop??

Please help me.

Comment: Well what *does* it give you?

Comment: it gives me path where solution files are stored.

Comment: What kind of path do you expect and what kind of path are you getting? Please always post "expected" vs "observed". Do not describe what you get, just the hard values.

Comment: @MartinMulder i have made edit in my question

Comment: how about this `string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("Your upload folder"), uploadedFile.GetName());`?

Comment: what is Path in this i didnt understood, then, what should i place for "Your upload folder" ... it totally gave me error

Comment: What do you mean with "appropriate"? If "appropriate" means: valid, than i must say the path is totally valid. If "appropriate" means that you expect something different, then tell us what you expect. Further more... is that path you gave the path on the server or the client? And do you expect a path which is on the server or client?

Comment: @MartinMulder I already mentioned what i expect, now i made it in bold with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file path will NEVER contain the path of the client's computers, because the software on the server is never allowed to take a peek inside the clients computer. If the server was alles to see inside the clients computer we would have a security issue.

The path you are getting is the local path at the server to where the file has been uploaded.

Comment: This is a security question.  WinForms and WPF apps have access to the local drive because they are operating on that machine and have given trusted access to the machine.  ASP.Net operated on a webserver and there is no direct access to the end-user's drive from the webserver.